# How can get user's email from onedrive API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

On the document, I just found I can get displayName from

```
/drive
```

But no email

[image]

If I want to use this API, can I only through Microsoft Graph?

Comment: Hello Zhiqin,
Currently the OneDrive api doesn't expose the email, just the displayName and the objectId. What scenario requires you to know the email address? Can you not work with the objectId?

Comment: If user bind two Onedrive in my app use same displayName,when i show all openfile history in a blanket list.I need one uniquely identifies and user can understand.ObjectId for the user is too difficult to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is available using the Microsoft Graph API , if your app has requested User.Read permissions.

You can make a request to get the signed in user's email:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mail

Or you can make a request to get a particular user's email, based on a user ID:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/mail

You can also use the createdByUser and lastModifiedByUser navigation properties on an item to retrieve the email address for the user who created/modified the file.

To call Microsoft Graph, you need to use the AAD OAuth v2 authorization / token end point. It's different than what you would have been using for OneDrive personal previously, but documented here: https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/graph_oauth.htm

Comment: This only works if the user is an Office365 subscriber. Accounts that are part of AAD but don't have an O365 license will see an error on those endpoints. Microsoft Accounts will see an error too.